# Can I prove a multivariable does not exist using polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus

So lets say I have a multivariable f limit and I solve it using polar coordinates. If in the end my result is something like sinθ does this mean the limit does not exist ?

Comment: **Hint:** If you let $\theta = \frac{k\pi}{2}$ and $\theta = k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer, what happens to your limit?